# AngularJS and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and wondered how I could get the PHP database results into an angular model. What I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="statsApp">
  <head>
    <title>Student Stats</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<?PHP
  // Include dbcreds.inc for db info.
  include('dbcreds.inc');

  if(isset($_GET['fname']) && $_GET['fname'] !== "")
  {
    $lname = $_GET['fname'] . "%";

    $sql = $conn->prepare("select * from students where fname like ?");

    $sql->execute(array($lname));

    $res = $sql->fetchAll();

    $rownum = 0;

    echo "\n    <SCRIPT>";
    echo "\n      var model = [";
    foreach($res as $r)
    {
      $rownum++;
      echo "\n        ";
      print_r(json_encode(array("ID" => intval($r['id']),"FNAME" => $r['fname'],"LNAME" => $r['lname'],"GPA" => doubleval($r['gpa']))));

      // Add a comma, if it's not the last datarow.
      if($rownum < count($res))
      {
        echo ",";
      }
    }

    echo "\n      ];";
    echo "\n      ";
    echo "\n      var statsApp = angular.module(\"statsApp\",[]);";
    echo "\n      ";
    echo "\n      statsApp.controller(\"statsAppCtrl\", function (\$scope) {";
    echo "\n        \$scope.stats = model;";
    echo "\n      });";

    echo "\n    </SCRIPT>\n  ";
  }
?>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="statsAppCtrl">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h2>
        <span class="label label-default">{{ stats.length }}</SPAN>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <TR>
            <TH>ID</TH>
            <TH>First Name</TH>
            <TH>Last Name</TH>
            <TH>GPA</TH>
          </TR>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr data-ng-repeat="stats_item in stats | orderBy:'ID'">
            <td>{{ stats_item.ID }}</td>
            <td>{{ stats_item.FNAME }}</td>
            <td>{{ stats_item.LNAME }}</td>
            <td>{{ stats_item.GPA }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

It seems to work ok, but I'm questioning whether I'm on the right track with this method of doing things. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely do not do it this way.  Create a file like students.php and then use $http in an Angular service to fetch the data.

Comment: Ok, so I jumped ahead too soon. I'm too novice in AngularJS to understand what you're saying. Conceptually, I get it, I think; PHP output json-encoded data and I make that my model?

Comment: Your Angular would looks something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cmnv20ps/ And the students.php file would echo out the json_encoded data and exit

Comment: Thanks! I can't mark this question as answered, but thanks.

Comment: this was a good example for me: https://github.com/lucentx/angular-crud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to make a call to a separate php file, which runs the query and echos a JSON encoded array for the Angular request to use.

Here is an example fiddle of the Angular side: https://jsfiddle.net/cmnv20ps/

```
function StudentsService($http) {
  var service = {
     getStudents: getStudents
  };

  return service;

  function getStudents(fname) {
     return $http.get('students.php', {
        params: {
           fname: fname
        }
     }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
     });
  }
}

function Controller(StudentsService) {
  var vm = this;

  StudentsService.getStudents('Ro').then(function(data) {
     vm.students = data.students;
  });
}
```

PHP Example:

```
$fname = $_GET["fname"];
$sql = $db->prepare("select * from students where fname like :fname");
$sql->execute(array("fname"=>"%" . $fname . "%"));
$res = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode(array("students"=>$res));
```